# Android Determine whether a multi-fragment layout should be used

Tags: android, android-fragments

When making apps for Android 3.x, you could basically just check if the device was in landscape to see if it could fit multiple fragments side by side. But this is only because you were basically guaranteed that the device is a tablet.

With the introduction of the compatibility library and android 4.0, I can't think of what I would consider as a 'good' way to determine if I can get away with side by side fragments or should revert to standard one fragment per 'screen.'

In the NewsReader example app, Google has a special values file for every common resolution, each with a Boolean value for whether the resolution should support the 2 fragment layout, but I think this way is poorly conceived. The only way I can think of is to check the size of the screen (to guess if it is a tablet or at least big enough to not ruin the layout), and then check the orientation.

So if anyone out there has an idea how to easily and efficiently check this, please let me know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually see the screen size type (small, normal, large, etc) by using the following:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK
```

That'll return an int that you can check against any of the following:

```
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_UNDEFINED
```

Then you can check for orientation, using

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Which will match any of the following possibilities

```
Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE
Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED
```

With this you can essentially simulate the multiple views by adding your fragments as space allows based on screen size and orientation.

Comment: Sweet! This is much nicer than I was planning on doing it... I feel I should have remembered these types of fields exist :)

Comment: Haha, I know how it goes.

Also, forgot to mention that those were just from 8 that I was targeting, SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE was added in 9 so you can be verbose with targeting.

Answer (score 4):

I create 2 layouts, one with one container (ViewGroup) for a fragment, and the second layout has 2 containers side by side. I use Android's folder structure for resources to specify that the scenarios where I want the multi-fragment (2 container) layout. Then in code, check for the existence of the second container to determine if you are multi-panel or not.

```
isMultipanel = false;
ViewGroup container2 = findViewById(R.id.container_2);
if (container2 != null) {
    isMultipanel = true;
}
```

Try not to think of it as tablet or phone, but rather wide enough or not wide enough for 2 panels.

If I wanted multi-panel on normal size devices (<= 5") and large (5" - 7") only when they are in landscape, but always on xlarge (> 7"), I would put the multi-panel layout file in:

- layout-land
- layout-large-land
- layout-xlarge

Then you don't have to do size checks in code since Android is already handling this for you.

Comment: I did see this option, but I am not doing this the normal way (for better or for worse). I am starting with a blank linear layout and adding as many fragments as I need (up to two). And since there will be several layers of options I want to be able to go through, I made it so that as you press options on a fragment (on the right in multi fragment view) the left fragment drops off (onto back stack), the right fragment scoots to the left, and the new fragment is added to the right. This is important because I can't load the fragments from scratch. Though maybe i could give the parent an id...